# Запускаю бота и пишет Proccess Finished exit code 0

Tags: python, aiogram

Делал своего бота запускаю его и процесс завершается и пишет эту ерунду
вот код

```py
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

bot = Bot(token="нельзя"
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
asymc def start_command_handler(message: types.Message):

#inline клавиатура
inline_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

#Сама инлайн кнопка
subscribe_button = InlineKeyboardButton("Подписаться", url=""")
    
    # Добавление кнопки в клавиатуру
    inline_keyboard.add(subscribe_button)

    # Отправка приветственного сообщения с инлайн-клавиатурой
    await message.reply("Привет, Бот. Обязательно подпишись на наш канал.", reply_markup=inline_keyboard)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Запуск бота
    from aiogram import executor
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Во-первых, исправьте форматирование, во-вторых покажите текст ошибки.

Comment: Может, потому что вы не знаете, как пишется слово `"__main__"`? [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)